# Make a Windows 8 metro app icon/panel larger. (not a win8 native app)

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

Some apps in Metro have a panel that is double the size of a smaller panel.
These apps include Photos, Music, People, Desktop, etc...
I can change between the states by right clicking on them, and use the "larger" or "smaller" buttons.

Other apps, including apps that you pin on your own, don't have a "larger" panel option.
Is there any work-around to enable this?
I've seen somewhere that you could change the image of a wide paneled app, but i haven't found anything about an app that has no "larger" mode.

TL;DR:

I have an app in metro, i want it to have a big panel like some of the other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you write the application? If so, search on stackoverflow.com for how to implement a "wide tile". If you didn't, there's almost certainly nothing you can do - the app doesn't support wide tiles. Presumably the developer didn't come up with a compelling Live Tile story - the most important use for wide tiles.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the app's code, or some sort of settings file, and make a wide tile of my own for the app, even if i didn't create it?